# How to stop gdalwarp creating world-spanning outputs near the dateline?

Tags: gdalwarp, srtm, antimeridian

I'm using gdalwarp to manipulate SRTM tiles near the the dateline (i.e. 180°, aka the antimeridian). SRTM tiles have a very slight (1/2 pixel) overlap with the meridian. You can see this using gdalinfo:

```
gdalinfo S16W180.hgt
Driver: SRTMHGT/SRTMHGT File Format
Files: S16W180.hgt
Size is 1201, 1201
[...]
Lower Left  (-180.0004167, -16.0004167) (180d 0' 1.50"W, 16d 0' 1.50"S)
Upper Right (-178.9995833, -14.9995833) (178d59'58.50"W, 14d59'58.50"S)
[...]
```

So the source spans the dateline by a tiny amount.

This causes problems with gdalwarp, which ends up creating huge globe-spanning outputs.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "epsg:900913" S16W180.hgt test.tif
gdalinfo test.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test.tif
Size is 1703, 5
[...]
Lower Left  (-20037508.330,-1806798.473) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 16d 7'13.00"S)
Upper Right (20032839.451,-1689152.120) (179d57'29.01"E, 15d 5'45.84"S)
```

Note the longitudes span (almost) the entire globe, and also the number of lines is unexpectedly small (5)

Is this a bug in gdalwarp? If not, what are the correct options to pass to gdalwarp to get a sensible output?

Comment: http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Australia/S16W180.hgt.zip in case you want to experiment.

Comment: add the SOURCE_EXTRA Parameter see http://code.google.com/p/maptiler/issues/detail?id=6 - try gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:900913 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=120 S16W180.hgt test.tif

Comment: maybe use -te argument for "target extents", or fix up the extents first using gdal_translate with a_ullr to overwrite the existing, or -projwin to cut out the bit you want within the bounds

Answer (score 2):

It works in two steps:

```
gdalwarp -te -180 -16 -179 -15 s16W180.hgt test.tif
gdalwarp -t_srs "epsg:3857" test.tif out.tif
```

The first command kicks off the extra half pixel on the wrong side of the 180° meridian.
You get an output file that is 1178P x 1222L.

Alternatively, with gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -180 -15 -179 -16 S16W180.hgt test2.tif
gdalwarp -t_srs "epsg:3857" test2.tif out2.tif
```

Creating an output file that is 1179P x 1223L.

Answer (score 2):

One easy workaround would be to specify the coordinate system "manually" as a PROJ string.  This allows you to use the [`+over`](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms#lon_wrapover-LongitudeWrapping) switch that disables wrapping on the antimeridian:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs \
    "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0 \
        +over +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null \
        +wktext +lon_wrap=-180 +no_defs" \
    S16W180.hgt test.tif
```

When I do that and then do `gdalinfo` on the result, I get this:

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-20037554.726,-1689152.120) (179d59'58.50"E, 14d59'58.50"S)
Lower Left  (-20037554.726,-1804766.925) (179d59'58.50"E, 16d 0' 1.37"S)
Upper Right (-19926099.407,-1689152.120) (178d59'57.11"W, 14d59'58.50"S)
Lower Right (-19926099.407,-1804766.925) (178d59'57.11"W, 16d 0' 1.37"S)
Center      (-19981827.066,-1746959.523) (179d29'59.30"W, 15d30' 2.12"S)
```

I got the PROJ string (without `+over`) from looking at the original output of `gdalinfo`.  It was included in an `EXTENSION[...]` block of the coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

As I was facing the same problem, I wrote a small shell script that finds out if the raster file crosses the dateline. If true, following option is added to gdalwarp:

```
--config CENTER_LONG 180
```

This is how the script works step by step:

1. Get WGS84 Extents from gdalinfo
2. If the **transformed** *ulx* and *lrx* **OR** *llx* and *urx* values are flipped compared to the original CRS, the transformed raster will cross the dateline.
3. If the dateline will be crossed, **--config CENTER_LONG 180** is added to gdalwarp.

---

**UPDATE** Better Version of the script, requires GDAL 2.0+ and Python:
Old version below.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Small Script to check if input raster will
# cross dateline when converting to EPSG:4326
# 
# USAGE: ./crosses_dateline.sh infile [outfile]
# 
# if no outfile is given, the script returns "true" or "false"
# if an outfile is given, gdalwarp is executed
# 
# Needs gdal 2.0+ and Python
# 


if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
    echo -e "Error: No input rasterfile given.\n> USAGE: ./crosses_dateline.sh infile [outfile]"
    exit
fi

# Get information, save it to variable as we need it several times
gdalinfo=$(gdalinfo "${1}" -json)

# If -json switch is not available exit!
if [ ! -z $(echo $gdalinfo | grep "^Usage:") ]; then
    echo -e "Error: GDAL command failed, Version 2.0+ is needed"
    exit
fi

function jsonq {
    echo "${1}" | python -c "import json,sys; jdata = sys.stdin.read(); data = json.loads(jdata); print(data${2});"
}

ulx=$(jsonq "$gdalinfo" "['wgs84Extent']['coordinates'][0][0][0]")
llx=$(jsonq "$gdalinfo" "['wgs84Extent']['coordinates'][0][1][0]")
lrx=$(jsonq "$gdalinfo" "['wgs84Extent']['coordinates'][0][3][0]")
urx=$(jsonq "$gdalinfo" "['wgs84Extent']['coordinates'][0][2][0]")

crossing_dateline=false
test $(echo "${ulx}>${lrx}" | bc) -eq 1 && crossing_dateline=true
test $(echo "${llx}>${urx}" | bc) -eq 1 && crossing_dateline=true

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "${crossing_dateline}"
elif [ "${crossing_dateline}" == "true" ]; then
    gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:4326" --config CENTER_LONG 180 "${1}" "${2}"
else
    gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:4326" "${1}" "${2}"
fi
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Check if input raster crosses dateline when converting to EPSG:4326
# 
# if no outfile is given, the script returns "true" or "false"
# if an outfile is given, gdalwarp is executed
# 

if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
    echo -e "Error: No input rasterfile given.\n> USAGE: ./crosses_dateline.sh infile [outfile]"
    exit
fi

# Get information, save it to variable as we need it several times
gdalinfo=$(gdalinfo "${1}")
# Read Source CRS
s_srs="EPSG:"$(echo "${gdalinfo}" | grep -Eo "^\s{4}AUTHORITY\[.*\]" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+")

# Transform corners to Target SRS and test if crossing dateline
t_srs="EPSG:4326"
crossing_dateline=false

if [ "${s_srs}" == "${t_srs}" ]; then
    xmin=$(echo "${gdalinfo}" | grep "Upper Left" | grep -Eo "[-0-9\.]+, +[-0-9\.]+" | grep -Eo "^[-0-9\.]*")
    xmax=$(echo "${gdalinfo}" | grep "Lower Right" | grep -Eo "[-0-9\.]+, +[-0-9\.]+" | grep -Eo "^[-0-9\.]*")
    test $(echo "(${xmax}-(${xmin})) / 1" | bc) -gt 180 && crossing_dateline=true
else
    # We need to check both diagonal lines for intersection with the dateline
    xmin=$(echo "${gdalinfo}" | grep "Upper Left" | grep -Eo "[-0-9\.]+, +[-0-9\.]+" | gdaltransform -s_srs "${s_srs}" -t_srs "${t_srs}" -output_xy | grep -Eo "^[-0-9\.]*")
    xmax=$(echo "${gdalinfo}" | grep "Lower Right" | grep -Eo "[-0-9\.]+, +[-0-9\.]+" | gdaltransform -s_srs "${s_srs}" -t_srs "${t_srs}" -output_xy | grep -Eo "^[-0-9\.]*")
    test $(echo "${xmin}>${xmax}" | bc) -eq 1 && crossing_dateline=true

    xmin=$(echo "${gdalinfo}" | grep "Lower Left" | grep -Eo "[-0-9\.]+, +[-0-9\.]+" | gdaltransform -s_srs "${s_srs}" -t_srs "${t_srs}" -output_xy | grep -Eo "^[-0-9\.]*")
    xmax=$(echo "${gdalinfo}" | grep "Upper Right" | grep -Eo "[-0-9\.]+, +[-0-9\.]+" | gdaltransform -s_srs "${s_srs}" -t_srs "${t_srs}" -output_xy | grep -Eo "^[-0-9\.]*")
    test $(echo "${xmin}>${xmax}" | bc) -eq 1 && crossing_dateline=true
fi


if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "${crossing_dateline}"
elif [ "${crossing_dateline}" == "true" ]; then
    gdalwarp -t_srs "${t_srs}" --config CENTER_LONG 180 "${1}" "${2}"
else
    gdalwarp -t_srs "${t_srs}" "${1}" "${2}"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

This is problem in the GDAL library.   It appears that GDALSuggestedWarpOutput() is giving weird output for width and height of the output file.

I haven't found a way to work around this yet.