# gdalwarp UTM Zone 1 to WGS84 - fails to transform

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I have a global dataset consisting of tiles in UTM projection that I want to mosaic and therefore need to reproject to a common projection.

Can I solve my reprojection error with  options to gdalwarp or do I need to manipulate the input files?

Reprojection is done with `gdalwarp` and the following command:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=LZW" N01_50.TIF N01_50_wgs84.TIF
```

Tiles in UTM Zone01 produce the following error and the result is visibly distorted (spans around the globe in E-W direction). All other tiles work fine.

```
ERROR 1: Too many points (441 out of 441) failed to transform, 
unable to compute output bounds. 
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 6006,0,6007,340,
```

Here is the output of `gdalsrsinfo` and the [download link of the input file (7.2 Mb)](http://www.mediafire.com/view/iyvgb0ysvtv4l0q/N01_50.TIF):

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 1N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-177],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["meters",1],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32601"]]
```

Comment: Reason for the problem must be that the image is crossing the dateline `Lower Left  (  284371.000, 5537970.000) (179d59'37.69"E, 49d57'18.33"N)
Upper Right (  715681.000, 6099540.000) (173d37'40.81"W, 54d59'45.36"N)` This question may deal with the same issue http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34117/how-to-stop-gdalwarp-creating-world-spanning-outputs-near-the-dateline.