# GDALWARP cuts off right edge of image?

Tags: coordinate-system, web-mapping, gdalwarp, web-mercator, antimeridian

I'm reprojecting GFS GRIB files to EPSG:3857 using gdalwarp. Resulting file get little bit shorter to the right so when I zoom in from zoom level 5 and higher, I can see vertical line with missing data. Check image below:

[image: vertical line with missing data]

When I check edges with gdalinfo I could clearly see that map is indeed shorter:

```
Upper Left  (-20037508.343,26491625.382)  (180d 0' 0.00"W, 88d12' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-20037508.343,-26492654.355) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 88d12' 1.05"S)
Upper Right (20036608.125,26491625.382)   (179d59'30.89"E, 88d12' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (20036608.125,-26492654.355)  (179d59'30.89"E, 88d12' 1.05"S)
Center      (    -450.109,    -514.486)   (0d 0'14.56"W,  0d 0'16.64"S)
```

For tile x = 32767; y = 14181; zoomLevel = 15; I calculated geo coords:

```
x0 = 20036285.349764004
x1 = 20037508.34221653
y0 = 2693029.380466357
y1 = 2694252.372918885
```

and I get complexly blank image.

For tile x = 63; y = 28; zoomLevel = 6; There is missing data vertical line at the right side of image.

I am using SOURCE_EXTRA=1000. I tried much higher numbers, but I guess resulting tif bounding box is not calculated correctly so this doesn't help.

Downloaded any grib2 file from [here](ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/)

Extracted 270 variable using wgrib2 tool with following grid params:

```
-new_grid latlon 180:23040:0.015625 -90:11520:0.015625
```

Finally, I used gdalwarp command:
`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 --config CENTER_LONG 0 -of GTiff --config GRIB_NORMALIZE_UNITS NO -co "TILED=YES" 270-16.grb test.tif`

Extracted and interpolated grib file: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/naa0338jsjt0uld/270-16.grb?dl=0)

Resulting TIF file: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/synissrv3ay6w6q/test.tif?dl=0)

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share some test data and exact gdalwarp command that you have used?

Comment: Updated original post with test data and more info

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of [How to stop gdalwarp creating world-spanning outputs near the dateline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34117/how-to-stop-gdalwarp-creating-world-spanning-outputs-near-the-dateline)

Try `--config CENTER_LONG 180`

Comment: Unfortunately, I get same results with CENTER_LONG 180

Comment: How about forcing the output to the mercator bounds `-te -20037508.3427892 -20037508.3427892 20037508.3427892 20037508.3427892`?