# Writing NetCDF file to TIFF with GDAL gives large gap in data

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I am downloading files from NOAA. I am using Python and trying to import a NetCDF file and create it into a TIFF raster. My version of GDAL is 2.3 and cannot be upgraded due to environment constraints. The script gives me an output that has a large gap in it and does not overlay correctly. Some of these libraries are used later in the script. What am I doing incorrectly?

I'm thinking there is something perhaps with the no data values. I inherited this script and that part might be hard coded in for another file. On the NOAA website it states "Missing data is flagged with a value of -9.96921e+36f." I have tried different ways of setting it, but am having trouble. Any pointers to set me in the right direction?

```
import arcpy, sys, string
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
import os
from osgeo import gdal
from scipy.io import netcdf
import numpy as np

in_file= "D:/NCEP_Monthly_nc_files/tmax.2m.gauss.2018.nc"
out_file = in_file.replace('nc', 'tif')

def hdf_subdataset_extraction(hdf_file, subdataset):
    """unpack a single subdataset from a HDF5 container and write to GeoTiff"""
    # open the dataset
    hdf_ds = gdal.Open(hdf_file, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    band_ds = gdal.Open(hdf_ds.GetSubDatasets()[subdataset][0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

    # read into numpy array
    band_array = band_ds.ReadAsArray().astype(np.int16)

    # convert no_data values
    band_array[band_array == -28672] = -32768

    # build output path
    band_path = os.path.join("output/", os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(hdf_file)[0]) + "-sd" + str(subdataset+1) + ".tif")

    # write raster
    out_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(band_path,
                                                  band_ds.RasterXSize,
                                                  band_ds.RasterYSize,
                                                  1,  #Number of bands
                                                  gdal.GDT_Int16,
                                                  ['COMPRESS=LZW', 'TILED=YES'])
    out_ds.SetGeoTransform(band_ds.GetGeoTransform())
    out_ds.SetProjection(band_ds.GetProjection())
    out_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(band_array)
    out_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-32768)


    out_ds = None  #close dataset to write to disc

    return band_path

out_file = hdf_subdataset_extraction(in_file, 1)
```

this is what the output looks like loaded into ArcGISPro 2.5:
[image]

I tried changing the setProjection part of the script to:

```
out_ds_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
out_ds_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
out_ds.SetProjection(out_ds_srs.ExportToWkt())
```

This results in the correct projection, but looks the same.

Additional info that may help. The GetGetoTransform() comes out as (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0).

Comment: Looks more like a projection issue than a no data issue, as the entire world seems to be included

Comment: I think you might be right. I tried adding code to correct the spatial reference/projection, however, it results in the same image.

Comment: I set the GeoTransform to [0, 1.875, 0, 85.06, 0, -1.875) and it looks correct, but it might be cutting off some information. The extent is Top 85.06, Bottom -91.19, Left 0, Right 360.0. I chose 85.06 since that's was WGS84 bounds are and then played around with the cell size. There has to be a more precise way to figure out what is happening.

Comment: The dateline makes challenges both for creating the dataset and for viewing it. The answers in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34117/how-to-stop-gdalwarp-creating-world-spanning-outputs-near-the-dateline may help with controlling the creation side.

Comment: I looked at the data from the NOAA website and it states that the spatial coverage is 0.0E to 357.5E, 90.0N to 90.0S. If the data only goes to 357.5 instead of 360 does that mean there is a gap/missing data in the file? https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.ncep.reanalysis.html